# Eloquent ORM - How to handle relationships with two instances of the same child model in parent model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a parent model called **Journey** that should relate to two instances of model-type **Address** - once for 'origin' and once for 'destination'. I can't work out what's the most efficient way of doing this. I would like to use Laravel's Eloquent ORM with eager-loading to achieve something elegant like the following when I return a journey:

```
return Journey::with('origin','destination');
```

I've tried the following:

1) Using Eloquent ORM's [one to one relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#one-to-one)

```
Journey
-------
id
user_id
date

Address
-------
id
journey_id
street
city
zipcode
```

Observations:

- Requires 'journey_id' in the Address model, meaning I can't really re-use this model for anything other than Journeys
- Address is linked to Journey as a whole, so I can't distinguish between origin and destination instances

2) Using Eloquent ORM's [polymorphic relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#polymorphic-relations)

```
Journey
-------
id
user_id
date

Address
-------
id
street
city
zipcode
addressable_id
addressable_type
```

Observations:

- I can now re-use the Address model with other models, but...
- Address is still linked to Journey as a whole, so I can't distinguish between origin and destination instances

3) Relating 'journey.origin' or 'journey.destination' by joining it to 'address.id'

```
Journey
-------
id
user_id
origin (address.id)
destination (address.id)
date

Address
-------
id
street
city
zipcode
```

Observations:

- I can now distinguish between the origin & destination instances, but...
- I think I have to use fluent queries for the joins, so I don't get origin & destination back as Address models
- There is no link back from the address to the journey

Does anyone have any suggestions for table / relationship structure that makes journey (with origin & destination) insertion and selection as elegant as possible, preferably using Eloquent so that I can utilise my model attributes and functions?

Also, although accessing the addresses through the Journey model will be the primary use case, I'd also like to be able to access the parent Journey through the Address model.

Comment: Will you have multiple `Journey`'s with the same `destionation` or `origin`?

Comment: That is the end goal. But for now I can live with addresses being duplicated if that makes it easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should have is:

**Database Strucuture**

```
Journey
---------
id
origin_id
destionation_id
user_id
date

Address
---------
id
street
city
zipcode
```

Then, link your `Journey` model to `Address` using a [One-to-Many](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#one-to-many) relationship:

**Journey.php**

```
class Journey extends Model {
    // ...

    public function origin() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Address');
    }

    public function destination() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Address');
    }
}
```

**Address.php**

```
class Address extends Model {
    // ...

    public function journeysAsOrigin() {
        return $this->hasMany('Journey', 'origin_id');
    }

    public function journeysAsDestination() {
        return $this->hasMany('Journey', 'destination_id');
    }
}
```